# flutter firebase pagination

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

In my flutter firebase app, I am trying to implement pagination to call ten documents, but I am finding it a bit challenging. At this point in my app, no document is being called, but documents were perfectly called without pagination at first, These are my codes below.

```
  int limit = 10;
  bool _hasNext = true;
  bool _isFetchingForum = false;
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  List<Forum> _forumList = [];
  final _forumSnapshot = <DocumentSnapshot>[];


  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _setupForumFeed();
  _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  _scrollController.addListener(() {
    if (_hideButtonController.offset >=
          _hideButtonController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        _hideButtonController.position.outOfRange) {
        if (_hasNext) {
          _setupForumFeed();
             }
           }
         }
```

This is on the widget page and calls the database method on another page with the limit passed to it

```
_setupForumFeed() async {
  if (_isFetchingForum) return;
  _isFetchingForum = true;
  List<Forum> forums = await DatabaseService.getFeedForums(
      widget.currentUserId, limit,
      startAfter: _forumSnapshot.isNotEmpty ? _forumSnapshot.last : null);
  if (forums.length < limit) {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _forumList = forums;
      });
    }
  }
  _isFetchingForum = false;
  print(_forumList.length.toString() + 'ffff');
}
```

This calls the list(10) of documents from the database.

```
static Future<List<Forum>> getFeedForums(String userId, int limit,
    {DocumentSnapshot startAfter}) async {
  if (startAfter == null) {
    QuerySnapshot forumFeedSnapShot = await forumFeedsRef
        .doc(userId)
        .collection('userForumFeed')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .limit(limit)
        .get();
    List<Forum> forums =
        forumFeedSnapShot.docs.map((doc) => Forum.fromDoc(doc)).toList();
    return forums;
  } else {
    QuerySnapshot forumFeedSnapShot = await forumFeedsRef
        .doc(userId)
        .collection('userForumFeed')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .startAfterDocument(startAfter)
        .limit(limit)
        .get();
    List<Forum> forums =
        forumFeedSnapShot.docs.map((doc) => Forum.fromDoc(doc)).toList();
    return forums;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you run the code in a debugger and step through `getFeedForums` line by line, 1) which branch of the `if` does it go into? 2) What are the values of `userId`, `startAfter` and `limit`?

Comment: if I run the code in a debugger and step through getFeedForums line by line, it goes into the first if statements, which indicates that startAfter at the moment is null,  the limit is 10,  and the userId is not null, am getting the right value of the userId. Thank You

Comment: So what's the value of `forumFeedSnapShot` then? Note that Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so I recommend you take more steps than the minimum I gave to get you started - and report on all of those if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you, sir, I was able to solve it, I made a mistake by passing the wrong value which is forum.length instead of _forumSnapshot.length to the if statement of the _setUpForumFeed on the widget page. But it is working now.